# Avoid sending multiple requests HTTP

Tags: apex, session

When I click a button I send a request to another server, I have to wait for the server's response
on the other side (may take 40 seconds)

I disabled the button to avoid multiple clicks, but when we refresh the page we can click again and send a second request before the first finishes.

I cannot make any changes to the external server to avoid duplicate creation.
I cannot save any data before sending a request.

I tried to use cache.session but it doesn't seem to work

```
if (!Cache.Session.contains('creationInProgess')) {                    
    Cache.Session.put('creationInProgess', true, 300);
} else {
    return 'creationInProgess';
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What is the button for the code? The problem doesn't have anything to do with the cache, technically speaking.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need some kind of locking mechanism. You don't saw where this button is, I'm going to assume it's on a record page for this, but you could also create a custom object called Mutex or similar and just store a single record in there. The idea anyway would be to query the record using `FOR UPDATE` before making the callout, this prevents other execution contexts (code from the clicked button included) from being able to modify it until your current transaction is complete.

Pseudocode:

```
onClick() {

  try {
    // acquire lock & do callout
    MyObject__c obj = [select Id from MyObject__c where Id = : thisPageRecordId for update limit 1];

    new HttpRequest.etc()

  } catch(QueryException qe) {
    //record already locked, button must have been clicked!
  }
}
```

There's more documentation around locking records here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_records.htm

I must admit I've never tried making a callout after lockign a record like this, could be that it's not allowed, but I've used locks to implement mutexes around long running tasks.

An alternative might be using a queueable or similar and checking to see if a job already exists.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already tried to lock the data, but it didn't work, this seems logical because locking prevents the record from being updated in SF, but not sending others requests to the external server.
I can't use asynch solution because I have to wait for the server response to display data based on the response (If we refresh the page, we have to show a message like "There is already a creation request being processed")

Comment: Out of interest what didn't work? Did it throw a particular kind of exception or something?

Comment: This doesn't generate any errors, the goal is to prevent duplicate creation requests in the external server (we cannot add a control in this server), normally it is the server which checks the duplicates, but unfortunately it doesn't do so, so i try in SF to avoid sending duplicate request to this server

Comment: But as long as the same record is being queried on each click then the second one won't be able to get access to it and should hit that exception

Comment: we can access the record, but when we try to update the record we encounter an exception. However, we can make multiple API requests before updating the record, and it's too late.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

1. We create the Salesforce record first, then we make the http request to Mulesoft for final record updates. We have an integration status that allows us to identify the backend status, i.e., none, success or failure. You could add "In Progress".
2. See https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_prevention.htm&type=5